# How do you deal with inverse trig functions that produce results outside their domain?

Tags: trigonometry

The problem I am facing is this:

Find $\cos(X) = 4/7$ in quadrant IV (of the Cartesian plane)

The next step leads me to this:

$X = \cos^{-1}(4/7)$

However, I know that the domain of Cosine inverse is restricted to quadrants I and II. So how do I answer the question? Is it no solution? Thank you for your time. Please let me know if I need to fix my question in any way.

Comment: What do you mean by quadrant 4? Do you mean the part of the graph cosine graph from $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ to $2\pi$?

Comment: By quadrant 4 I mean in the cartesian plane.

Comment: On the graph of the cosine curve?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the graph of cosine inverse is limited to the first and second quadrant of the cartesian plane. I may be wrong though.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question, I am going to delete some of my comments as they are not useful.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I do not know the answer to your question - it is probably a matter of definition. Hopefully someone else can answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the diagram below:

[image: fourth-quadrant_angle_with_given_cosine]

Observe that 
$$\cos\theta = \cos(-\theta) = \cos\varphi = \frac{4}{7}$$
Moreover, the first-quadrant angle I have labeled $\theta$ satisfies
$$\theta = \arccos\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)$$
Thus, one fourth-quadrant angle with cosine equal to $4/7$ is $-\theta$.  If you want one that satisfies the inequalities $0 \leq x < 2\pi$, then set 
$$x = \varphi = 2\pi - \theta = 2\pi - \arccos\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

By "quadrant IV" I assume you mean the range $\frac{3\pi}2 \le X \le 2\pi$. You are right that using the inverse cosine function will not answer this question as stated, because the values of the inverse cosine, by definition, always lie between $0$ and $\pi$. However, basic properties of trig functions should allow you to reduce to this case. For example, it is true that $\cos (2\pi-\theta) = \cos\theta$ for all $\theta$. Can you use this to reduce to the "quadrant I" case, which I know you can sovle?

Comment: So basically I need to do Cos inverse of (2π-4/7)?